# Should I make a copy or scan of a check before depositing checks whenever possible?

Tags: banking, check

Or can I simply take a picture of the check with my cellphone before depositing the check, just in case there is a disputed transaction?

Comment: Why not hold on to the check until it clears?

Comment: What do you mean by that? The physical copy of the check is gone when I deposit it.

Comment: The question in confusing. Are you asking should i make a copy of the check? or is there some other receipt involved?

Comment: I'm asking if it's a good idea for me to make a copy of the check before physically depositing it, just in case a disputed transaction occurs.

Comment: how a copy is going to help you in case a dispute arises? You have transaction recorded in bank statement of yours and the opposite party.

Comment: All these comments seem to be missing the point.  What if you put a check into an ATM and later the bank says they never got it.

Answer (score 7):

The need to make a copy/scan depends on the method of deposit.

- Mail: Yes make a copy. If the letter never makes it to the bank, it is nice to know all the details when you make request for a replacement. Check number, date, invoice number...
- ATM: If they give you a scanned image, then keep it in case the bank makes a mistake when it processes it. If your bank doesn't provide a scanned image, then make a copy/scan before going to the ATM
- Teller: you should walk out the door with receipt, keep it.
- Electronic: the software should give you a scanned image back, plus you have the original.

Once the bank has credited it to your account, some online banking systems might show you a scanned image. They generally do of the checks that you write, but not all have them of the ones you deposit.

I prefer a scan over a copy because I want an electronic file so that I can attach it to an email if I need to, or can keep it with my other tax receipts.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I don't print anything. Your bank will most likely provide a scanned image via their online banking website (I know Chase does).

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the check, but you have to write "copy" on it so you don't run into trouble with the law. There have been countless times where people have copied checks and tried to pass it off as original to get twice the money. That of course is illegal so write somewhere on it that it is a copy and not to be deposited.